# ionic 4 importing IonInfiniteScroll throws error at compile time as no exported members

Tags: ionic-framework, infinite-scroll

I am trying to implement infinite scroll and the import statement like below

```
import { IonInfiniteScroll } from '@ionic/angular';
```

shows me a error in the editor that ../@ionic/angular/dist/index has no exported members.

my package.json has

```
    "@ionic/angular": "4.0.0-beta.16",
```

Answer (score 0):

i realized that this a 11 months old version. updated to 4.11.x and did a clean build and it worked fine